# Using AutoMapper inside LINQ query .NET Core/EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have model classes `User` and `Course`. Then I have a third model class which serves as a lookup table called `CoursesForUser`.

These classes look something like this:

```
public class User 
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class CoursesForUser 
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string CourseId { get; set; }
     public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Course 
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public ICollection<CoursesForUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In AutoMapper, I have the following mappings:

```
CreateMap<User, UserInfoDto>();
CreateMap<CoursesForUser, ListOfCoursesForUserDto>();
```

I have a repo query that I'm writing which should return a Dto. That Dto is called `UserInfoDto` and looks like this:

```
public class UserInfoDto 
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public ICollection<ListOfCoursesForUserDto> CourseList { get; set; }
}
```

The query looks like this:

```
public async Task<UserInfoDto> GetUserInfo(string userId)
{
    var user = from u in _context.Users
               where u.Id == userId
               join ucourses in _context.CoursesForUser on u.Id equals ucourses.UserId
               select new UserInfoDto
               {
                   Id = u.Id,
                   CourseList = _mapper.Map<List<ListOfCoursesForUserDto>>(ucourses)
               };
    return await user.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

However, the code is breaking on that line:

```
CourseList = _mapper.Map
```

AutoMapper is throwing an error so I'm sure my syntax is wrong, I just don't know where it's wrong. Any help?

Comment: AM is not a part of EF Core and this query is not translatable. There are lot of tricks how to make it work, not simple with third party libraries. But I suggest just do not use AM for custom projections at all.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: The mapping type is different. `List<ListOfCoursesForUserDto>` and `ListOfCoursesForUserDto`